# 3D plotting in GUI using python/Matplotlib or 3D plotting in C#/illnumerics?

Tags: c#, python, user-interface, matplotlib, ilnumerics

I have lot of data in csv files(which keeps increasing with time) which I upload to a SQL server 2012. Now I need to access and analyse this data using 2D and 3D plots(example: http://scidavis.sourceforge.net/help/manual/pics/exemple-plot3d.png). These 3D plots I would either embed in my GUI or display in separate window. Also in the GUI I would vary lots of parameters to see the changing results.

I have found 3 approaches to do this so far:

1. Access the SQL table from python script, use pyQT for creating the
   GUI, and Matplotlib and other relevant python libraries to create 3D
   plots.
2. Access the SQL table from C# code, create GUI using WPF, and create
   3D plots using 3rd party ilnumerics library. so far I have been
   having trouble using ilnumerics, its usage seems to be inactive, no one has been downloading it from sourceforge.net. But one more    problem is ilnumerics is free only for academic and evaluation purposes. and I would be using it in a office.
3. Access the SQL table from Matlab, Create GUI in Matlab, and create
   3D plots using Matlab.

I have ruled out number 3 because of slow speed of Matlab, and not so good GUI in Matlab.
Among 1 and 2 which one is the best approach. or are there any more better approaches to do this.

I am familiar with C, C++, MFC, python beginners level, Matlab beginner to moderate proficiency. I would have to learn new stuffs/programming languages anyways, so I am not keeping existing skills as a consideration.

I might use machine learning techniques to analyse data later, I saw support for machine learning in python libraries, so this could be a advantage to use python.

Answer (score 1):

ILNumerics is designed to support situations like yours. It is best suited for dynamically changing plots and general visualizations in 2D and 3D - embedded into custom GUIs. Keep in mind some considerations:

- ILNumerics plot panels works best with Windows.Forms. But it has been
  sucessfully used inside WPF by help of the WPF WinFormsHost control.
- There are two editions of ILNumerics: Community Edition and
  Professional Edition. The Community edition is GPLv3. It is provided
  for free to anyone and not restricted to academic or private use
  (unlike Matlab, which comes with considerable costs for anyone as you
  know).
- There is a machine learning package in ILNumerics as well. It
  contains some clustering algorithms, EM, regressions, knn, pca and
  the like.

Check out the full feature list: http://ilnumerics.net/specifications.html

Comment: You answers is very useful. I am also convinced to use ilnumerics, however I am stuck into a new problem please check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952825/unable-to-add-ilnumerics-controls-into-vs2012-toolbox-manually-or-automatically