# Unable to add ILNumerics controls into VS2012 toolbox manually or automatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, ilnumerics

I am trying to follow the instruction in http://ilnumerics.net/visualization-api-quick-start-guide.html to get ilnumerics working. I have so far been unable to ILnumerics controls on my toolbox.

I tried all three separate package from Nuget

1) ILNumerics (AnyCPU)
2) ILNumerics.32bit
3) ILNumerics.64bit

These package do get loaded to my .csproj, but the IlNumerics Controls are not listed in the toolbox. So I tried to add them manually. I right click on my tool box and select 'Choose items'. This takes me to .Net framework components tab, where I select the Browse button and try to load the DLL. I get the following errors for above three cases

1) ILNumerics.dll : There are no components in ILNumerics.dll that can be placed in the toolbox.
2) ILNumerics.32.dll : There are no components in ILNumerics32.dll that can be placed in the toolbox.
3) ILNumerics.64.dll : The file ILNumerics64.dll is not valid. (Note: this is a different error than previous two cases)

I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012", OS is Microsoft Windows 7 professional, and the system type is X64-based PC.

I am not sure if this relevant but when I ran dependency walker on the above three dlls. 
I got the below error for ILNumerics.dll and ILNumerics.32.dll 
    "Error: Modules with different CPU types were found"

I am able also to execute the console application example give in http://ilnumerics.net/quickstart.html using all three ways shown above.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the toolbox before adding the controls manually? Right Click on the toolbox and select "Reset"

Comment: ILNumerics.32Bit and ILNumerics.64Bit are deprecated. You should use ILNumerics (AnyCPU) instead!

Comment: yes I have tried resetting the toolbox before adding the controls manually.
yes I am trying to use ILNumerics (AnyCPU) which is also mentioned in the question

Comment: Well as of now I found a workaround which works but I don't know why.
I used a another PC with similar configuration, In which the whole procedure worked and i was able to create a running sample project. The whole project from other computer I copied to my computer and I opened the solution file and built\ran the application. Now I tried to add the ILNumerics Toolbox using the DLL from this working project. Doing this added the IlNumerics Controls to my toolbox. I am able to use this dll to added controls to my toolbox. I don't know this works yet. Perhaps I need to look at some settings.

Comment: You may find out by looking at the project files. Compare the xml content. I could think of some references to outdated versions causing the effect you described?

Comment: SOLVED: since I was working with C# project I was working under project folder C#Demo and the character # was causing the problem. so in VS2012, choose items, we have trouble loading dll from a path containing # character.
oh dear god :/ don't know if its my fault, back to programming after quite a break.

Comment: I am glad you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. My workaround is to drag a simple Panel from the toolbox and then got and edit the InitializeComponent() function and change the type of the member to ILPanel. After this I have access to the ILPanel properties